# Nested models throws Undefined Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've been following [RailsCast 197](http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-197) to try this nested models/forms and have cracked my head over this code for over 2 hours, but to no avail.  What am I overlooking?

I have the following Models:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :performed_exercises, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :performed_exercises
end

class PerformedExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :exercise
  has_many :performed_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :performed_sets
end

class PerformedSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :performed_exercise
end
```

In my WorkoutsController I have the following:

```
  def new
    # We only need to build one of each since they will be added dynamically
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.performed_exercises.build
    @workout.performed_exercises.performed_sets.build
  end
```

When I run the test and invoke the controller in the browser, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `performed_sets' for #<Class:0x7f6ef6fa6560>
```

Thanks in advance for any help - my RoR noobility ceases to amaze me!

**Edit**:
fflyer05: I tried using the same code as the RailsCast with the iterating over the collection, as well as attempting to build the performed_sets on performed_exercises[0] - but it doesn't work. Doing anything else, I get an uninitialized constant PerformedExercise::PerformedSet error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model methods should be called on a single object.  You are calling them on a collection on objects which will not work, `@workout.performed_exercises[0].performed_sets` will.

Notice the code from the Rails cast 196:

```
# surveys_controller.rb
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  3.times do
    question = @survey.questions.build
    4.times { question.answers.build }
  end
end
```

You would have to loop through each nested method in order to build your form.

If code like this:

```
for performed_exercise in @workout.performed_exercises
     for performed_set in performed_exercise.performed_sets
      # something interesting
     end
end
```

does not work, I would check to be sure that your model file names are correct (rails needs them to be singular) in your case you should have `workout.rb`,`performed_exercise.rb` and `performed_set.rb` for those respective models.

Your relationships' definitions look correct, so wrong file names is the only thing I can think of that can be wrong.

Comment: Thanks soooo much fflyer05.  My PerformedSet model file name was performed_sets.